# USB Ethernet Adapter Not automatically "seen" by JVM after computer restart

Tags: windows-10, networking, usb, drivers, ethernet

I have software (Proprietary, runs in a JVM) running on a windows 11 PC that utilises the "Stock" Ethernet adapter for secure comms (https) between itself and field devices and a USB ethernet adapter for "third party" comms (Modbus TCP). This issue happens on windows 7,10 and 11 PCs.
The problem is, whenever the PC restarts, the JVM loses the USB-ETH interface and it must be reselected manually. The stock NIC is always fine.
I suspect it has something to do with the software looking for the USB adapter at a certain (address?) but upon restarting the adapter looks different to the JVM config, or isnt loaded.
I am not sure how these adapters load and if they take a hardware address like an old school 232 COM port or are entirely ephemeral?

How can I lock in the specifics of the USB adapter so it is always available, for example a static connection so the software can always see it even if its disconnected? Or how to ensure it always "loads" identically on each restart?
Thanks

Comment: Do you start the JVM after the USB interface is detected or before? Have you tried a different interface (in particular, have you considered a PCI Ethernet interface instead of USB)?